# Error parsing JSON array in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have recently settup a php page on my server that runs through my database and outputs this onto the page.

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://abc.com/getjson.php");

        try{

            JSONArray  myArray = json.getJSONArray("date");

            for(int i=0;i<myArray.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = myArray.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("date", "date name:" + e.getString("date"));
                map.put("activity", "activity: " +  e.getString("activity"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }
```

http://abc.com/getjson.php outputs:

```
[{"date":"2012-04-23","activity":"gym"},{"date":"2012-04-24","activity":"walkin‌​g"}]
```

Comment: What is `json` and how do you get it? Which error message do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729102/android-json-array-returns-transform-error-103/13922033#13922033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse  json string as to get date  :

```
JSONArray  myArray=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://abc.com/getjson.php");

for(int i=0;i<myArray.length();i++){

JSONObject  myobj = myArray.getJSONObject(i);

 // get date here
  String strdate=myobj.getString("date");

 // get activity here
  String stractivity=myobj.getString("activity");
}
```

because current json String Structure is `JSONArray -> JSONObject -> key-value` .

**EDIT :** you will  need to change return type of `getJSONfromURL` method to `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` because you are getting JSONArray as root element instead of JSONObject from server

Comment: I believe the problem is here: JSONArray  myArray=new JSONArray("your json string"); myArray is null because "your json string" doesn't exist in my JSON that I'm fetching from the web.

Comment: @EGHDK :  "your json string" means your current string which you are getting from server like in question "[{"date":"2012-04-23","activity":"gym"},{"date":"2012-04-24","activity":"walking"}]" put it in place of "your json string"

Comment: Error in eclipse: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Comment: @EGHDK : plz post your latest code and where u are getting this error ?

Comment: "json cannot be resolved" on "JSONObject  myobj = json.getJSONObject(i);" Do I need that line anymore?

Comment: @EGHDK : yes we need change `JSONObject myobj = json.getJSONObject(i);` to `JSONObject myobj = myArray.getJSONObject(i);`